# Ember Handlebars raw output without processing

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to display a handlebars code sample in my Ember App. The sample would look like

```
{{#bm-select}}
  {{#bm-selected}}
    {{name}}
  {{/bm-selected}}
{{/bm-selected}}
```

How could I add this to my template and make handlebars not process it? I just want to display the code like above.

- I tried stuff like `\{{bm-select}}`.
- Using raw block helpers but I don't think Ember's Handlebars support this.

Comment: Curly braces can be escaped using a backslash \\ 
example,
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/valogusulo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @melc i feel very stupid. Just had to add a \ to every curly brace. I just added on the top and thought it would affect every where. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: thanks I posted it, it may assist others. To be honest it wasn't very clear in other SO threads. This thread. https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/146  helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curly braces can be escaped in handlebars template using a backslash \ .

example,

emberjs.jsbin.com/valogusulo/1/edit?html,js,output

```
\{{#bm-select}}<br/>
  \{{#bm-selected}}<br/>
    \{{name}}<br/>
  \{{/bm-selected}}<br/>
\{{/bm-selected}}
```